# Integral of specific square root of arcsin function $\int{(a^2-x^2)\sin^{-1}\left(\frac{b}{\sqrt{a^2-x^2}}\right)\ dx}$

Tags: integration, roots

I'm trying to resolve the following integral:
$$\int{(a^2-x^2)\ \sin^{-1}\left(\frac{b}{\sqrt{a^2-x^2}}\right)\ dx}$$
I don't find any good work around (substitution, by parts, ...).
If I put this integral in an application like Wolfram, I get imaginary parts or elementary functions with again a negative square root.

Comment: Maybe $x = a\cos(t)$, but I am not sure it will be easy.

Comment: Any chance that $b$ is supposed to be an $a$?

Comment: If you set $y \to b/(a^2 - x^2)$ or equivalently $x\to \frac{\sqrt{a^2 y-b}}{\sqrt{y}}$, so as to get a $\sin^{-1}(y)$ term, then Mathematica gives a result in terms of elliptic functions.

Answer (score 2):

Start by integrating by parts, and you will get
$$
(a^2x-x^3/3)\arcsin(b/\sqrt{a^2-x^2})-b\int\frac{x^2(a^2-x^2/3)}{(a^2-x^2)\sqrt{a^2-b^2-x^2}}\,dx
$$
To take care of the new integral, let $u=x/\sqrt{a^2-b^2-x^2}$. You will get an ugly, but doable integral of a rational function. The result is (I leave those details to you)
$$
\frac{b(a^2-b^2)u}{6(1+u^2)}+\frac{b}{6}(3a^2+b^2)\arctan u-\frac{2}{3}a^3\arctan(bu/a)
$$
which gives the final result, after returning to $x$ and simplifying a bit,

> $$\begin{aligned}\int(a^2-x^2)\arcsin\frac{b}{\sqrt{a^2-x^2}}\,dx&=\frac{1}{6}\biggl[(6a^2x-2x^3)\arcsin\Bigl(\frac{b}{\sqrt{a^2-x^2}}\Bigr)\\ &\qquad +bx\sqrt{a^2-b^2-x^2}\\&\qquad+b(3a^2+b^2)\arctan\Bigl(\frac{x}{\sqrt{a^2-b^2-x^2}}\Bigr)\\&\qquad-4a^3\arctan\Bigl(\frac{bx}{a\sqrt{a^2-b^2-x^2}}\Bigr)\biggr]+C.\end{aligned}$$

Comment: Thank you very much! This was the solution I was looking for!

Comment: Hi,
I had another integral of a similar function. Do I have to substitute also similar to the one above? I manage to do the first step by integrating by parts but then I got lost. This is the integral:
∫(a^2−x^2)*sin−1(-1 + (b/sqrt(a^2−x^2)) dx
Thanks in advance!

Comment: I suggest that you ask a new question for your new integral.

Comment: OK I did: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2258924/integral-of-special-asin-inta2-x2-sin-1-left-1-fracb-sqrta2-x2

Answer (score 1):

I think by substituting  $$x=\frac{a}{\cos t}, \quad dx=a\frac{\sin t}{\cos^2t}dt$$
we obtain
$$\int (a^2-\frac{a^2}{\cos^2t})\sin^{-1}(\frac{b}{\sqrt{a^2-\frac{a^2}{\cos^2t}}})a\frac{\sin t}{\cos^2t}dt=$$
$$\int (\frac{a^2\cos^2t-a^2}{\cos^2t})\sin^{-1}(\frac{b}{\sqrt{\frac{a^2\cos^2t-a^2}{\cos^2t}}})a\frac{\sin t}{cos^2t}dt=$$

$$\int (\frac{-a^2\sin^2t}{\cos^2t})\sin^{-1}(\frac{b}{a\sqrt{\frac{-\sin^2t}{\cos^2t}}})a\frac{\sin t}{\cos^2t}dt=$$
$$\int (-a^2\tan^2t)\sin^{-1}(\frac{b \cot t}{ia})a\frac{\sin t}{\cos^2t}dt$$
Here I stop. You can complete it by calculating the $\sin^{-1}(\frac{b}{ia}\cot t)$.

I hope it helps you.

Comment: What ? why would you rollback my edit ? I just converted `$sin$` to `$\sin$` . it's just uglier now.

Comment: @A---B I wanted to edit one math part and I had to copy and paste the answer whole again...sorry about that ;). Now I edit that again. Thanks.