# Integral of special asin $\int{(a^2-x^2)\sin^{-1}\left(-1+\frac{b}{\sqrt{a^2-x^2}}\right)\ dx}$

Tags: integration

I'm looking for the solution of following integral:

$$\int{(a^2-x^2)\sin^{-1}\left(-1+\frac{b}{\sqrt{a^2-x^2}}\right)\ dx}$$

Can anyone help me on this? I started with integration by parts but then I got lost.

$$ u=\sin^{-1}\left(-1+\frac{b}{\sqrt{a^2-x^2}}\right) $$
$$ dv=(a^2-x^2) $$

$$
(a^2x-x^3/3)\arcsin(b/\sqrt{a^2-x^2})-b\int\frac{x^2(a^2-x^2/3)}{(a^2-x^2)\sqrt{2b\sqrt{a^2-x^2}-b^2}}\,dx
$$

As mentioned in a similar post, now a substitution could be proposed:
$u=x/\sqrt{2b\sqrt{a^2-x^2}-b^2}$.

But here I got into problems. I don't see how to resolve this any further. See also [Integral of specific square root of arcsin function $\int{(a^2-x^2)\sin^{-1}\left(\frac{b}{\sqrt{a^2-x^2}}\right)\ dx}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2250234/integral-of-specific-square-root-of-arcsin-function-inta2-x2-sin-1-lef/2250360#2250360)

Thanks and regards!

Comment: Wolfran says it's not expressable as a standard mathematical function. Not looking good..

Comment: It looks like a rather ugly integral. Are you sure you wrote the correct expression in the integral?

Comment: When we substitue $x = a\sin u$ and do then integration by parts. I think WA can calculate the second integral https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=int+(9sin(u)+%2B+sin+3u)(sec(u))%2Fsqrt(b+sec(u)+(2+a+-+b+sec(u)))+du.

Comment: Doez the integral have bounds? Otherwise, we cannot evaluate it meaningfully.

Comment: Yes it does, from -L to L with L <= a.

Comment: Hint 1: define
$$I(a,b,x):=\int_{-L}^{L}{(a^2-x^2)\sin^{-1}\left(-1+\frac{b}{\sqrt{a^2-x^2}}\right)\ dx}$$

Hint 2: Can you find $$\frac{d}{da} I(a,x)$$
Hint 3: Leibniz's trick to differentiate under the integral sign