# How to calculate arcsin integral

Tags: integration

This question might have an obvious answer, but my math is not very strong,
and I've been thinking and searching textbooks for a while now, 
to no avail. So, how would one solve the following integral?

$$\int \sin^{-1}\left(\dfrac{a}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}\right)dx$$

where a $\in$ R, $ -1\leqslant x \leqslant 1 $

The above problem is my simplification of another problem I encountered
in the following paper:

http://www.cad.zju.edu.cn/home/xgliu/papers/PG06-SphereSet.pdf

Original line (page 4): 
$S(x) = \left[φ - \sin^{-1}\left(\dfrac{l_o}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}\right)\right] - \dfrac{1}{2}\left(\sqrt{1 - x^2 - l_o^2} - l_1\right)l_o $

Thank you very much.

Comment: Does it exist? Yes. Is it pretty? No. http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integral+of+arcsin(a%2Fsqrt(1-x%5E2))

Comment: Thank you, I've already seen that, but I'm not sure if I should trust wolfram... I suppose the answers are just not very good, even if correct...

Comment: I suppose you are correct. Try some numerical examples to confirm Wolfram did it correctly. Also, see here https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2258924/269764

Answer (score 1):

Note that the integrand $$f(a,x) = \sin^{-1} \frac{a}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}$$ is real-valued only if $a^2 + x^2 \le 1$.  Let $$I(a) = \int f(a,x) \, dx.$$
Then integration by parts with the choice $$u = \sin^{-1} \frac{a}{\sqrt{1-x^2}} \, \quad du = \frac{ax}{(1-x^2)^{3/2} (1 - a^2/(1-x^2))^{1/2}} \, dx = \frac{ax}{(1-x^2)\sqrt{1-a^2-x^2}} \, dx, \\ dv = dx, \quad v = x,$$ yields $$I(a) = \int \sin^{-1} \frac{a}{\sqrt{1-x^2}} \, dx = x \sin^{-1} \frac{a}{\sqrt{1-x^2}} - \int \frac{ax^2}{(1-x^2)\sqrt{1-a^2-x^2}} \, dx.$$  Then with the trigonometric substitution $$x = \sqrt{1-a^2} \sin \theta, \quad dx = \sqrt{1-a^2} \cos \theta \, d\theta,$$ the remaining integral is $$\int \frac{a (1-a^2) \sin^2 \theta}{1 - (1-a^2) \sin^2 \theta} \, d\theta = a \int \left( -1 + \frac{1}{1-(1-a^2) \sin^2 \theta} \right) d\theta. $$  Now all that remains is to show $$\int \frac{d\theta}{1 - c \sin^2 \theta} = \frac{\tanh^{-1} \sqrt{c-1} \tan \theta}{\sqrt{c-1}} + C,$$ which I leave as an exercise for the reader.

Comment: Thank you very much, if all goes well, I'll make sure to mention you in my thesis.